# Angular-ng serve- Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I am getting this error on **ng serve** the angular project. **ng build --prod is working fine**

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[4916:00000276B1C57010]   588109 ms: Scavenge (reduce) 8180.7 (8204.3) -> 8180.6 (8205.1) MB, 36.1 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.081, current mu = 0.007) allocation failure
[4916:00000276B1C57010]   673012 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 8181.3 (8202.1) -> 8181.0 (8203.3) MB, 84897.4 / 0.6 ms  (average mu = 0.041, current mu = 0.003) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF6A3CF3E0F napi_wrap+108911
 2: 00007FF6A3C97E16 v8::base::CPU::has_sse+61910
 3: 00007FF6A3C98D16 node::OnFatalError+294
 4: 00007FF6A4570CEE v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached+94
 5: 00007FF6A4555ACD v8::SharedArrayBuffer::Externalize+781
 6: 00007FF6A43FF95C v8::internal::Heap::EphemeronKeyWriteBarrierFromCode+1516
 7: 00007FF6A440ACEA v8::internal::Heap::ProtectUnprotectedMemoryChunks+1258
 8: 00007FF6A4407E99 v8::internal::Heap::PageFlagsAreConsistent+2457
 9: 00007FF6A43FCA71 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage+2033
10: 00007FF6A43FAC95 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateExternalBackingStore+1349
11: 00007FF6A441AFEB v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject+203
12: 00007FF6A4149F81 v8::internal::interpreter::JumpTableTargetOffsets::iterator::operator=+1409
13: 00007FF6A45F9BAD v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+465229
14: 00007FF6A459378D v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+46381
15: 00000360181DD9FC
```

Node version: ***v14.17.0***

Angular:

```
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 11.0.5
Node: 14.17.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 11.0.5
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1100.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1100.5
@angular-devkit/core            11.0.5
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.0.5
@angular/cdk                    11.2.13
@angular/material               11.1.2
@schematics/angular             11.0.5
@schematics/update              0.1100.5
rxjs                            6.6.3
typescript                      4.0.5
```

I have tried various commands but none of them works:
***>node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve***

Comment: trying to run `npm start` command

Comment: npm start will simply run the command that is associated to start in  script of package.json, which in my case is ng serve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try this command:

```
node --max_old_space_size=8048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve
```

which I've seen in a pretty similar post. This should fix the javascript memory heap issue temporary

Comment: I have tried this already but it is not working, getting the same response :(

Comment: Everyone say that, without trying to understand the real issue. This is not a solution but instead a workaround which may work or not.